# Need inputs on how a Controller or Rest Endpoint can be made hidden for a particular environment

Tags: spring-boot

There are various option provided in Spring framework like using @Conditionxxx annotations and Spring profiles, I am trying to use @ConditionOnProperty but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] and update your question with code and complete error

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for controller

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        value="env", 
        havingValue = "test", 
        matchIfMissing = false)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/poc/")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    String getTest() {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

In application.properties file, add below line

```
env=test
```

if you change env value in property file to dev, your controller won't get registered.